Symfony isGranted subject
I have this code that works fine:
#[Route("/test", name: "crm_test")]
#[IsGranted('viewPage', 'permissions')]
public function testAction($permissions = ["xxx", "yyy"])
{
    return new JsonResponse(["status" => "OK"]);
}

Is there a way to not need $permissions variable in testAction method?, setting that in a IsGranted parameter or Expression or something?
I tried this but didn't work
#[Route("/test", name: "crm_test")]
#[IsGranted('viewPage', ["xxx", "yyy"])]
public function testAction()
{
    return new JsonResponse(["status" => "OK"]);
}

